# Using BeautifulSoup, returning multiple unique values in find_all python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

First post as a user, long time reader. I'm currently trying to use python and BeautifulSoup/selenium/chromedriver to parse an airfare website ([html](https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/select.html?originationAirportCode=ISP&destinationAirportCode=PBI&returnAirportCode=&departureDate=2019-02-01&departureTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&returnDate=&returnTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&adultPassengersCount=1&seniorPassengersCount=0&fareType=USD&passengerType=ADULT&tripType=oneway&promoCode=&reset=true&redirectToVision=true&int=HOMEQBOMAIR&leapfrogRequest=true))

This is the current code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Tanner PC\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("Listed above in summary")
sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")'

for wga in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'currency currency_dollars'}):
fare=wga.find('span',{"class":"swa-g-screen-reader-only"})

print(fare.text)
```

When using this code, it will only scrape an individual fare for the times the span in listed in the webpage code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Looking for a print of all fares on the screen, should be from html element: <span class="swa-g-screen-reader-only">[value] Dollars</span>

Comment: just fares without any associated info?

Comment: That is my goal, I am creating separate objects for each element. I also realized that "swa-g-screen-reader-only" is in head, which could be problematic

Answer (score 0):

Just move your print inside of the for loop

```
for wga in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'currency currency_dollars'}):
    fare=wga.find('span',{"class":"swa-g-screen-reader-only"})
    print(fare.text)
```

I got the output like this.

```
547.58 Dollars
519.58 Dollars
314.80 Dollars
538.98 Dollars
510.98 Dollars
426.98 Dollars
547.58 Dollars
519.58 Dollars
248.80 Dollars
547.58 Dollars
519.58 Dollars
248.80 Dollars
538.98 Dollars
510.98 Dollars
311.98 Dollars
547.58 Dollars
519.58 Dollars
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple mistake. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Bitto, I had a follow up that I'm very much struggling with. What if I wanted to segment it so it only showed the "Wanna get Away" class of fares?

Comment: for wga in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'currency currency_dollars'})[2::3]:

Comment: @TannerAsadorian See my comment above. "Wanna get Away" every third element in the resulting list.